# How to find JsonPath for a Key

Tags: json

Let's I have a sample JSON as below and I wish to **get jsonPath for key** say "city"

```
{
  "fname" : "A",
  "lname" : "B",
  "city" : "LA" 
}
```

I am open for either

1. Browser Extension
2. Java Library
3. Sublime/Atom extension

Answer (score 0):

1. Install JSONView Chrome browser extension.
2. Open any URL which returns JSON. Right click on any key. It gives you context menu to copy jsonPath and jsonValue

To enable it for files loaded from disk instead of URL, Go to Manage Extension and Under JsonView select "Allow Access to File Urls" check box.